# Android Studio unable to run app on version 31 or above

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have developed an android app that is working perfectly alright on android versions less than `31`. For version 31 or greater I am getting the following error

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable,
> e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

**Code**

```
 public static void initSyncReceiver(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncReciver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 23231, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if (!Common.SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreference(context, context.getString(R.string.survey_sync_settings_key), true)) {
        if (alarmUp) {
            //alarm is up but not needed
            Log.e(TAG, "sync booking alarm is up but not needed, canceling..");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    23231, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "sync booking alarm neither up nor needed...");
        }
        return;
    }
    setAlarm(intent, context, 23231, 5);
    Log.e(TAG, "sync booking alarm needed so setting...");
}
```

I am getting the error on `boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 23231, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);`

I have already migrated to `androidx`. But no result.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When creating the pending intent with `PendingIntent.get*` (even with `FLAG_NO_CREATE` I guess) you have to add that flag, e.g. `..., PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE) ;` (bitwise "or" `|` adds bit flags). And not sure about that but wouldn't `alarmManager.cancel(alarmUp)` already do the trick?

Comment: where to add `alarmManager.cancel(alarmUp)`

Comment: I meant `if (alarmUp) { alarmManager.cancel(alarmUp); }` instead of creating a new updated intent just to cancel it. Not sure if that works though. but https://stackoverflow.com/a/28922621/995891 looks like you don't have  to do that nor cancel the intent itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG\_IMMUTABLE or FLAG\_MUTABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919110/how-to-solve-this-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your app targets Android 12 or higher, you must specify the mutability of each PendingIntent object that your app creates.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent

In short, add `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` to other `PendingIntent` flags.

Whether it's mutable or not depends. For alarms, it's normally immutable.

For example, before:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Now:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
```

If you target Android 5 or lower, you need:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    } else {
        0
    }
```

P.S. I happened to read [this commit](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/commit/69775d8be49499eee79507a3915a4a11cb4331b5) today. It has a similar modification.

Updated code for the question:

```
 public static void initSyncReceiver(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncReciver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 23231, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE) != null);
    if (!Common.SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreference(context, context.getString(R.string.survey_sync_settings_key), true)) {
        if (alarmUp) {
            //alarm is up but not needed
            Log.e(TAG, "sync booking alarm is up but not needed, canceling..");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    23231, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "sync booking alarm neither up nor needed...");
        }
        return;
    }
    setAlarm(intent, context, 23231, 5);
    Log.e(TAG, "sync booking alarm needed so setting...");
}
```

Comment: So I should replace `boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 23231, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);` with `boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 23231, intent, PendingIntent.PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE) != null);` ?

Comment: @Moeez The answer is updated. You could copy and paste.