# MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent() Giving Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or

Tags: kotlin, audio, media-player, android-mediasession, mediasession

I made an audio application that shows a foreground notification in the notification tray with play/pause controls. It was working fine but after Android S started to get the "Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires..." error. Here is the little piece of code responsible for crash.

```
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(description.title)
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(description.subtitle)
        notificationBuilder.setSubText(description.description)
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
        notificationBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        notificationBuilder.setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))
```

MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent() is giving the crash for not giving FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE for the pending intent. But that is within android class itself and out of control.

Here is the crash report:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.islambook: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
                 Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
                    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
                    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
                    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
                    at androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.java:274)
                    at androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.java:234)
                    at com.islambook.Audio.MediaStyleHelper.from(MediaStyleHelper.kt:42)
```

Comment: Have you tried this fix? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69152986/3738870

Comment: But that is for "f you are NOT USING PendingIntent anywhere" but media notification action builder MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent() is using PendingIntent and i cannot avoid it.

Comment: You can still give it a try, maybe it will fix the problem.

Comment: yes thanks i gave it a try. but error is still there.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. I was using old media classes. I had to add this to app > build.gradle

`implementation("androidx.media:media:1.6.0")`